# Oozie launch script after Coordinator Start

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I'm looking for a way to launch a custom script when a coordinator start.

So when a coordinator start the running of a job, I'd need to make for example an api call to a third party service.

Is there a way or a workaround to make this possible?

Thank you

Comment: if you want to launch/execute the script for each workflow launched by coordinator then essentially you can add an shell action in the workflow itself. Note: This shell script will be executed on a node (random) in the hadoop cluster.

Comment: Yes this would be an option but if it's possible, I'm looking for something more general, if I could tell to oozie to do this would be better instead of modify the workflows. Do you have any other idea? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: the key is the property oozie.wf.workflow.notification.url

add in the workflow configuration file, the following parameter

```
<property>
<name>oozie.wf.workflow.notification.url</name>
<value>http://server_name:8080/oozieNotification/jobUpdate?jobId=$jobId%26status=$status</value>
```

and create a webservice listening on this url